# Raspberry pi 3B running Buster cannot set language to en_GB.UTF8

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to set my R-pi3 to en_GB.UTF8 locale.
On Bullseye the settings entered in the RPI Imager work fine and are saved correctly when writing the SD card, but that OS has issues with graphics on RPi3 so I am stuck with the Buster OS. The settings used to download the OS to the SD card with rpi imager appear to be ignored for Buster. After setting up the card the config page insists on reverting to US language.

Once installed, no matter what I select in raspi-config, it sets itself back to en_US.UTF8.
I have tried editing all the locale settings I can find but the issue persists. I am using the rpi terminal rather than SSH so that eliminates the external link problem from SSH that has been mentioned elsewhere.
It seems to be a common issue with Buster OS from the number of requests on line for help, although it is usually to change from GB to US, especially the keyboard.

Setting the locale seems to be OK from the command line: sudo locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 until I try set update the seting.

When I run the line sudo update-locale en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 it comes back with the warning:<<
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.>>

running locale gives message:
Cannot set file to LC_CTYPE to default locale, no such file or directory
Cannot set file to LC_MRESSAGES to default locale, no such file or directory
Cannot set file to LC_ALL to default locale, no such file or directory

Below that all listings are en_US.UTF8

Any ideas would be appreciated as the failure to set en_GB is causing problems with other software that tries to use en_GB.UTF8 as its locale setting.

UPDATE****************************************************************

I just re-wrote another card and left everything as it was, no change to locale etc, and after updating let it reboot. Running loacle confrimed that everything was set to US.

I then changed the local language, keyboard etc in the GUI menu/preference/Raspberry Pi configuration to English and GB. Also set the keyboard to UK layout.

Ran locale again and it is all now set to GB. Amazing! After several days of fiddling, it appears that the on screen menus work but the config (raspi-config) does not.

The lesson here (for Buster anyway) seems to be get it set up and updated after a new install, reboot then do the modifications to language and keyboard in the GUI rather than from the terminal.

Comment: what I find odd is that (in my experience, which dates back to wheezy or maybe even squeeze) , `en_GB.UTF-8` is the default for pi

Comment: Yes, supposedly the difficulty is changing it to US. Maybe it was initially because I was doing it throught PuTTY, although I could not get it to go through the built in terminal either. Strange!  See update above.